# Make a Div Expand to the Left insteaf of the Right | framer-motion and react

Tags: css, reactjs, transition, framer-motion, chakra-ui

I have a simple transition that I created using `framer-motion` and `chakra-ui`. If you are not familiar with `chakra-ui` a flex is nothing but just a `div` with the `display` set to `flex`.
This is what it looks like:

[image]

I'm trying to do the exact same transition just with the difference that the width should expand to the left and not to the right. The word "Link" can appear on either side of the icon, it's not important.

Here's the code I'm working with:

```js
<Flex width={"4em"} height={"4em"}>
    <Flex as={motion.div}
        zIndex={6}
        backgroundColor={"white"}
        whileHover={{ width: "unset", borderRadius: "15px", }}
        whileTap={{ scale: 0.9 }}
        style={{ originX: "50%", originY: "50%" }}
        position={"absolute"}
        shadow={"lg"}
        name={"Copy URL"}
        width={"4em"}
        height={"4em"}
        borderRadius={"50%"}
        onClick={copyURL}
        overflowX={"hidden"}
    >
        <Flex alignItems={"center"} justifyContent={"center"} grow={0} minWidth={"4em"} height={"4em"} >
            <BiLink fontSize={"2rem"} />
        </Flex>
        <Flex fontSize={"2em"} marginRight={"1em"} alignItems={"center"} justifyContent={"center"} height={"100%"}>
            Link
        </Flex>
    </Flex>
</Flex>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try adding following styles:

```
{ 
  position: absolute,
  top: 0,
  right: 0
}
```